# Disable company-mode in minibuffer

Tags: emacs

I've set up company to load globally like this:

```
(let ((company-path "path/to/company"))
  (add-to-list 'load-path company-path)
  (autoload 'company-mode "company" nil t)
  (global-company-mode t))
```

The problem is that it loads anew every time the minibuffer gets focus. Is there an easy way to disable this behavior? I would like to have it enabled in every file buffer, but not minibuffer.

Thanks.

**Update:**

A few clarifications.

First of all, what makes me think `company-mode` loads every time I switch to minibuffer? Well, every time I type `C-x` of `M-x`, the minibuffer shows "Pymacs loading ropemacs..." and hangs for a split second. This behavior can be observed only with the `global-company-mode` enabled, so I blamed it on the `company`.

However, why blaming `company` if it says `pymacs`, right? So I went on and turned off the loading of `pymacs` which looked like this in my .emacs file (taken straight from its installation instructions):

```
(defun load-pymacs ()
  "Self-explanatory."
  (add-to-list 'load-path (make-plugin-path "Pymacs"))
  (autoload 'pymacs-apply "pymacs")
  (autoload 'pymacs-call "pymacs")
  (autoload 'pymacs-eval "pymacs" nil t)
  (autoload 'pymacs-exec "pymacs" nil t)
  (autoload 'pymacs-load "pymacs" nil t))
; make-plugin-path is a function defined somewhere else in my .emacs file.

(load-pymacs)
```

After commenting out the last line and restarting Emacs, the "Pymacs loading ropemacs..." message was gone even with `company-mode` enabled globally. However, I still had to manually eval `(company-mode)` before `(global-company-mode t)` would work.

After this little investigation, I'd like to rephrase the original question a bit. I'm not familiar with the concepts of `require` and `autoload` in Emacs, so I'm asking for an advice here:

What exactly do I need to place in my .emacs file to make `company` automatically turn on in every file-buffer (and not in minibuffer) and have Pymacs enabled along with it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have the latest version? I was curious, so I tried it out by installing the [ELPA](http://tromey.com/elpa/) package (listed as version 0.5), and enabled `global-company-mode`, and it doesn't activate in the minibuffer for me. The ELPA package takes care of the autoloads as well.

If there's still a problem, you may be able to use `minibuffer-setup-hook` (which is called whenever the minibuffer gets focus), to switch company mode off in that buffer.

FWIW, your code looks a bit odd to me. The `let` variable is only used by the following line, so isn't really needed, and unless there's some automagic behaviour I'm not aware of, that autoload must be redundant if you can successfully call `global-company-mode` without a similar declaration -- presumably either the library's own autoload comments have been processed, or the library has been loaded already?

Comment: Thanks for the link to ELPA. I've done a little more investigation and updated the question with a more detailed explanation. I would really appreciate it if you took a look at it. Thanks.