# Disabling paredit in minibuffers

Tags: emacs, paredit

I'm using [starter-kit-lisp](https://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit) with Emacs 24.3.1, and it turns `paredit-mode` on in many buffers, including the minibuffer. This is extremely frustrating when I'm doing a regexp search, as paredit has no clue about regexps and won't let me enter certain characters in certain places. :)

I'd like to disable `paredit-mode` for all minibuffers.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Disable company-mode in minibuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298053/disable-company-mode-in-minibuffer), there is a `minibuffer-setup-hook`, but using `(remove-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook 'paredit-mode)` doesn't seem to work. However, the `paredit-mode` function itself takes an optional argument, so one can disable `paredit-mode` in minibuffers by adding the following to `init.el`:

```
(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook (lambda () (paredit-mode 0)))
```

Thanks to [Magnar Sveen](https://github.com/magnars/.emacs.d/blob/master/setup-paredit.el#L62-L63) for the hint!

This is a bit of a hack, of course. It would be better to stop paredit from ever being enabled. Following [immerrr]'s(https://stackoverflow.com/users/944617/immerrr) suggestions in the comments:

```
C-h v minibuffer-setup-hook <RET>

minibuffer-setup-hook is a variable defined in `C source code'.
Its value is
((lambda nil
   (paredit-mode 0))
 ido-minibuffer-setup rfn-eshadow-setup-minibuffer minibuffer-history-isearch-setup minibuffer-history-initialize)
```

I suspect that `ido-minibuffer-setup` may well be the culprit. I'll keep digging on this, and update the answer once I find something useful.

Comment: I went ahead and posted this question and answer after figuring out how to do it, because searching Stack Overflow and Google for "disable paredit minibuffer" didn't yield anything useful. :)

Comment: It seems from your message that you misunderstood emacs hooks, because I'm not sure how one would "use remove-hook to disable a hook." In emacs, a hook is a variable (simple list actually) that contains functions to be called upon some event, so remove-hook should be used to remove one of the functions attached to that hook.

Comment: OK, terminology fail, then. Something (and I'm assuming that something is `starter-kit-lisp`) is adding the `paredit-mode` function to the `minibuffer-setup-hook`. Given this, it should logically follow that  `remove-hook` should be able to remove `paredit-mode` from the list of functions attached to that hook. Have I got it right now? If so, I'll edit the question to clarify.

Comment: I'm now wondering if starter-kit-lisp is actually adding `paredit-mode` to the `minibuffer-setup-hook` at all. Perhaps it is adding some other function that enables paredit (perhaps conditionally), and this is why my attempts to remove `paredit-mode` had no effect. I browsed through the starter-kit-lisp source, but it was not immediately obvious how it was enabling paredit in minibuffers.

Comment: I'd use emacs introspection for that, just look at the value of minibuffer-setup-hook `(describe-variable 'minibuffer-setup-hook)` or `C-h v minibuffer-setup-hook <RET>`. From there one could try disabling one by one and see removing which one helped.

Comment: I'd also look for `turn-on-paredit-mode`, not `paredit-mode` because the latter when called without arguments (which is how hook functions are called) not enables but toggles the mode.

Comment: Interesting; its value is `(ido-minibuffer-setup rfn-eshadow-setup-minibuffer minibuffer-history-isearch-setup minibuffer-history-initialize)`. I bet `ido-minibuffer-setup` is the culprit.

Comment: That's weird, ido-minibuffer-setup should not do that.